# JavaScriptで文字列がwell-formedなXMLかチェックしたい

Tags: javascript

やりたいこととして、http://mizchi.github.io/md2react/ で、markdownのHTML直接入力の記法で、壊れたHTMLを入力した際に検出して警告を出そうとしていました。

最初は次のリンクを参考に、下のようなコードを書きました
[Check for XML errors using JavaScript - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334119/check-for-xml-errors-using-javascript)

```
parser = new DOMParser()
checkValidXML = (xmlString) ->
  parsererrorNS = parser.parseFromString('INVALID', 'text/xml').getElementsByTagName("parsererror")[0].namespaceURI
  dom = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, 'text/xml')

  if dom.getElementsByTagNameNS(parsererrorNS, 'parsererror').length > 0
    throw new Error('Error parsing XML')
  return dom;
```

ただ、この場合は `<a>foo</a>` や `<span>aaa</span>` を誤検出してしまいます。本当に検知したいのは`<a>foo</` のような中途半端な文字列です。

divやpreは通ります。(現状のmd2reactの実装では、少しでも安全側に寄せて誤検出を許容しています)

この実装もDOMParserに依存しているので、nodeでも動くようにできればピュアなJSの実装で、正しく壊れたHTML(XML)を検出したいのですが、より良い方法や、既存実装があったりしませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

isInvalidXML関数が`"<a>"`と`"</a>"`とで、二回実行されているようです。

consoleから直接、isInvalidXML関数に対して文字列`"<a>foo</a>"`を送ると、
問題なく結果が返ってくるようなので、
問題はisInvalidXMLが呼ばれる以前にあるのではないかと思われます。

あまり深く追ってはいませんが、compile関数のnode.valueの時点で既に`"<a>"`だけになっているようですね。